# Insert textbox value in magento database

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, jquery

I am new to Magento. I am trying to insert Textbox value into database on button click. I am using this code for calling controller function.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery( function() 
{
 jQuery("#savedb").click( function()
 { 
 jQuery.ajax( 
 {
  url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('modulename/index/methodname'); ?>",
  type: 'POST', 
  async: false, 
  dataType: 'text',
  processData: false,
  data: { 
  a: $('#title').val(),
  b: $('#content').val(), 
  c: $('#status').val() 
}, 
});
});
}); 
</script>
```

But this is not working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to jquery.

Comment: Could you also post any javascript issues, the controller that is receiving the request and any other relevant code?